# mvvmcross with autoview menu viewmodel + view with android layout

Tags: mvvmcross

I would like to define my options menu from my viewmodel using autoviews. I have implemented IMvxAutoDialogViewModel in my viewmodel and defined the menu. I also have a view defined a corresponding android layout for that view. It is my understanding that views and layouts take priority over what is defined in my viewmodel in the case of autoviews. Is it possible to create kind of a hybrid where I define only the menu section from my viewmodel and have that injected into my view that is defined with a android layout?

I get no options menu when I do the following:

```cs
public class MainViewModel
    : MvxViewModel, IMvxAutoDialogViewModel
{
    public KeyedDescription GetAutoView(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case MvxAutoViewConstants.Menu:
                return GetMenuAutoView();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public bool SupportsAutoView(string type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case MvxAutoViewConstants.Menu:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private KeyedDescription GetMenuAutoView()
    {
        var auto = new ParentMenuAuto()
        {
            new MenuAuto(caption: "System",
                longCaption: "System",
                command: ()=> ShowSystemViewModelCommand)
        };

        return auto.ToParentMenuDescription();
    }
}
```

```cs
[Activity(Label = "Main")]
public class MainView : MvxActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create kind of a hybrid where I define only the menu section from my viewmodel and have that injected into my view that is defined with a android layout?

Yes, it will be possible to do this - but doing so will take some digging through the autoviews source code to work out how they work.

A good starting place for this might be the auto dialog activity: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.AutoView.Droid/Views/Dialog/MvxAutoDialogActivity.cs

---

Alternatively, at a practical level, if all you need is some viewmodel-defined menu items, then you may find this easier and simpler to craft yourself using a little Reflection code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Stuart! I crafted my own code to add the context menu items using reflection as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks - please do edit my answer - or provide your own - to let others know how to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

Per Stuarts suggestion, I am offering what I ultimately implemented.

```cs
public interface IVbMvxMenu
{
    List<VbMvxMenuItem> MenuItems { get; }
}

public class VbMvxMenuItem
{
    public VbMvxMenuItem(string caption = null, string longCaption = null, ICommand command = null)
    {
        this.Caption = caption;
        this.LongCaption = longCaption;
        this.Command = command;
    }

    public string Caption { get; private set; }
    public string LongCaption { get; private set; }
    public ICommand Command {get; private set;}
}
```

I implement IVbMvxMenu on a view model. Example implementation:

```cs
public class MainViewModel
    : MvxViewModel, IVbMvxMenu
{
    private List<VbMvxMenuItem> _items = null;
    public List<VbMvxMenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _items ?? new List<VbMvxMenuItem>()
            {
                new VbMvxMenuItem(
                    longCaption: "System",
                    caption: "System",
                    command: ShowSystemViewModelCommand)
            };
        }
    }

    MvxCommand _showSystemViewModelCommand;
    public System.Windows.Input.ICommand ShowSystemViewModelCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _showSystemViewModelCommand = _showSystemViewModelCommand ?? new MvxCommand(DoShowSystemViewModelCommand);
            return _showSystemViewModelCommand;
        }
    }

    void DoShowSystemViewModelCommand()
    {
        base.ShowViewModel<SystemViewModel>();
    }
}
```

I did the following to wire everything up to the view:

```cs
    public class MyMenuClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, IMenuItemOnMenuItemClickListener
    {
        private ICommand _menuClickCommand = null;
        private IMenuItem _menuItem = null;

        public MyMenuClickListener(IMenuItem menuItem, ICommand menuClickCommand)
        {
            _menuClickCommand = menuClickCommand;
            _menuItem = menuItem;
        }

        public bool OnMenuItemClick(IMenuItem item)
        {
            if (item == _menuItem && _menuClickCommand != null)
            {
                _menuClickCommand.Execute(null);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then in my activity, I override OnCreateOptionsMenu with the following:

```cs
    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(Android.Views.IMenu menu)
    {
        IVbMvxMenu viewModelMenu = base.ViewModel as IVbMvxMenu;
        if (viewModelMenu != null && viewModelMenu.MenuItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in viewModelMenu.MenuItems)
            {
                var menuItem = menu.Add(new Java.Lang.String(item.LongCaption));
                menuItem.SetTitleCondensed(new Java.Lang.String(item.Caption));
                menuItem.SetOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuClickListener(menuItem, item.Command));
            };
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```